# Copy a texture generated by DirectX into an OpenGL texture directly through VRAM

Tags: qt, opengl, directx, gpu

We have a DirectX-only application that uses the QT framework.
QT can renders its GUI through GPU in an OpenGL texture, but not in DirectX.
We would like to be able to render our DirectX application (DirectX) inside a QT Widget (OpenGL)

Is there a simple way to copy a texture generated by DirectX, into an OpenGL texture directly through VRAM, without an intermediate copy in RAM?

We thought about CUDA to make this copy inside the GPU...

Comment: Not much option but [NVidia have a suitable extension](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/WGL_NV_DX_interop.txt) if that's any help.

Comment: Extension will do it, but it sounds like a dog's breakfast to me.